# Use specific sql server database by user input

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error while trying to use a database by an user input.
Need help.
Please find the codes.

```
$dbname = $_POST['db_name'];

if(!empty($_POST['db_name']))
  {
    $query ="USE'".$dbname."'";
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);
    if($stmt === false){
    die ( print_r (sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
   }
```

Error Message:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102
>   [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'HMS_CCO'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'HMS_CCO'.
>   ) )

Comment: `USE` needs double quotes, you have single quotes. So just swap the quotes on the `$query...` line.

Answer (score 1):

Put a blank space after keyword `USE` and remove the single quote `'`.

`$query ="USE ".$dbname;`

Comment: Really glad to hear that. please accept my answer if it really helped you.